# Finding $f$ such that $f'(x)=A(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, linear-transformations

The problem is the following:

> Let $U\subset \Bbb R^m$ open and simply connected and $A: U \to \mathcal{L}(\Bbb R^m; \Bbb R^n)$ a differentiable application. Show that there exists $f:U\to\Bbb R^n$ twice differentiable satisfying $f'(x)=A(x)$ for all $x\in U$ if and only if $A$ satisfies $\big( A'(x) v \big) w = \big( A'(x) w \big) v$ for all $v, w\in\Bbb R^m$.

The first part is easy and follows from the Schwarz Theorem for applications, since $A'(x)=f''(x)$. I aim to show the converse, but couldn't find a candidate for $f$. Any hints?  Further, why do we need the simply connected hypothesis?

Answer (score 1):

Let us write $A = (A_1, \ldots, A_n)$, so that each $A_j \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is a differentiable (hence continuous) vector field in $U$.

It is well-known that, if $U$ is simply connected and the vector field $A_j$ is
irrotational, i.e. $\partial_k A_{ji} = \partial_i A_{jk}$, then the vector field is conservative, i.e. there exists a scalar function $f_j \colon U \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla f_j = A_j$.
Your last assumption is equivalent to the request that each $A_j$ is irrotational.

Now, it is enough to define $f=(f_1, \ldots f_n) \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: *"Your last assumption is equivalent to the request that each $A_j$ is irrotational."* Well, this is the core of the problem - everything else is quite trivial. How do you show that a partial differential relation ($\text{curl } A_j = 0$) is equivalent to a purely algebraic one ($A'vw = A'wv$)?

Comment: Ok. We can try choosing $v = e_j$, $w = e_k$.